# Edit the picture field of registration form

Tags: media, users

I am building a Drupal 7 site, and using the [Hybridauth module](https://drupal.org/project/hybridauth) and [Media module](https://drupal.org/project/media)

When user login with Hybridauth - their picture is saved under the core picture field of the user registration. Thus, I can't create new image field for the user registration form.

I used the [reg with pic module](https://drupal.org/project/reg_with_pic) to allow users that register in the normal way, through the registration form, to upload their picture.

Now, I want to use the core Image type field on the core picture field of the user, so I can edit the picture field. In addition, it will be great if I could use the media module on this picture field of the users, for better experience when uploading pictures in the registration form.

- How can I change the picture field of the users to be "Field Type: Image"?
- How can I use the media module with it?

Comment: You can't change it, `picture` is a hard-coded property of the user entity type. You could theoretically remove it via update/alter hooks but there's no telling how core/contrib modules that are expecting that property to exist would react. If you want to use an image field you'll just have to add a new field

Comment: @Clive thanks for the answer. if I will create a new image field - can I make Hybridauth  save the user profile picture from facebook on the new image field I created?

Comment: @EB84 have you found a solution for your question about how to save image from facebook to an image field ?